# Catching the NumberFormatException

Tags: java, numberformatexception

Below is the class somebody else wrote.

The problem that I am facing is that when it get's into the `parse method` with `null as the rawString`, it is throwing `NumberFormatException`.

So what I was thinking to do is, I should catch that NumberFormatException and `set the value itself as null`. So the way I did is right?

```
public class ByteAttr {

    @JExType(sequence = 1)
    private Byte value;

    public static ByteAttr parse(String rawString) {
        ByteAttr attr = new ByteAttr();
        try {
            attr.setValue(Byte.valueOf(rawString));
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfEx) {
            attr.setValue(null);
        }
        return attr;
    }

    public Byte getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public void setValue(Byte value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO it would be better to set 0 or -1 to indicate that there's no value and to not have a `NullPointerException` later in your program/application.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I disagree; a null value is perfectly acceptable and nullchecks should be used later in the program anyway. `0` and `-1` are both valid values, so they shouldn't be used to indicate the lack thereof.

Comment: @Vulcan it depends on design. That's why I said IMO :). You could have a valid point but I've found tons of null checks before getting to the real code so I prefer a default value instead of `null` and lot of nullchecks and `NPE` anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct approach depends on what you want to accomplish in the program.

- If it makes sense for `ByteAttr.getValue()` to return `null` later in your program, then your approach could work.
- However, you need to consider whether you *should* be throwing an exception if `parse` is called with an indecipherable argument (including `null`). An alternative is to catch the `NumberFormatException` and throw a different exception that has semantic meaning in your program.

```
    public static ByteAttr parse(String rawString) throws BadAttributeException {
        ByteAttr attr = new ByteAttr();
        try {
            attr.setValue(Byte.valueOf(rawString));
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfEx) {
            throw new BadAttributeException(nfEx); // wrap original exception
        }
        return attr;
    }
```

- Another technique is to pass a default value to `parse` for those cases when `rawString` is indecipherable:

```
    public static ByteAttr parse(String rawString, Byte defaultValue) {
        ByteAttr attr = new ByteAttr();
        try {
            attr.setValue(Byte.valueOf(rawString));
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfEx) {
            attr.setValue(default);
        }
        return attr;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do four things:

1. Decide what an unparsable number string means in the context in which you will be using the method. Does it mean an internal problem in the program? A corrupt file? A user typo? Nothing wrong but that string needs to be handled differently?
2. Decide the best way to handle it, taking that into account. Almost always, if the error is triggered by external input you need to report it back. Substituting null **may** be a good way of handling it.
3. Document what you decide to do. If a method is going to return null with some specific meaning, that needs to be written down as comments, preferably Javadoc commments.
4. Implement your decision.

I get the impression, perhaps unfairly, that you have jumped straight to step 4, without thinking through the possible causes and proper reporting of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an early exit with a condition like:

```
if (rawString != null) {
    return attr; // or other value you prefer
}
```

You can also make sure the caller of the parse method test for null value and avoid calling parse when it is.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the tolerance to null values in your application. If you expect the users to not pass null string to the `parse()` method, then you should do a defensive null check and throw an exception.

```
if (null == rawString) {
    throw new CustomException("rawString cannot be null");
}
```

The same would apply to the catch block for NumberFormatException, where instead of silently setting the value of Byte attribute to null, you should throw an exception with appropriate message.

But if `null` is perfectly acceptable, then you should perform a defensive null check and set the Byte attribute to null. The NumberFormatException should certainly be NOT suppressed, IMHO.